# Cause of tiled artifacts in render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, artifacts

Following image is my first attempt on rendering using cycles. Unfortunately I get some artifacts and I have no clue why. It doesn't show up like this in the viewport, only when rendered.

[image: Interesting cycles render]

**Q:** How to get rid of this 'blocky/tiled artifacts' in my render?
[image]

Comment: Hi John! Since this is just a test scene I suggest to provide your file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to get a quick answer. Btw: This site is no regular forum: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Hardware (GPU) for sure. AMD? Update your drivers, Use the latest version of blender... But without info is hard to help you further

Comment: Using NVIDIA hardware. All up-to-date, latest safe version installed. Blend file added

Comment: Hello :). Interesting bug. *GPU only* rendering works fine, but CPU or Hybrid rendering results in artifacts on my end. I'd report it as a bug.